# Java URLConnection response is encoded

Tags: java, urlconnection

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
public class testa {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String nextLine = "";
        URL url = null;
        URLConnection urlConn = null;       
        InputStreamReader  inStream = null;
        BufferedReader buff = null;
        try{
            url  = new URL("https://kickass.to");
            urlConn = url.openConnection();      
            ((HttpsURLConnection) urlConn).setHostnameVerifier(new Verifier());
            inStream = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream());
            buff= new BufferedReader(inStream);
            while(nextLine != null){
                nextLine = buff.readLine();
                System.out.println(nextLine);               
            }   
        }catch(MalformedURLException e){
               System.out.println("Please check the URL:" +  e.toString() );
        } catch(IOException  e1){
            System.out.println("Can't read  from the Internet: "+ e1.toString() ); 
        }        
    }

 }
```

Hey, I want to get the source code of this website, the code works when I use it on other website but when I do it on www.kickass.to, the response is encoded or something and looks like this

```
iÞŠpÃ2÷4rqy"pc‚Q‚ßÑÄ¶vnæö2”cnä.>*‰˜›m(Ïú¿p*s²™„­J.û’›TÔÓµÄé¸˜aÈº3ÛTYÜè¾Eúm9ìbQ.n‚+ô"§€¾AêtY.¾ƒàj4Gœ9ðõaˆoPz–¡¹‹Ìo÷9íyh´4½ ÷ ¾ÏÀ|«M?E©Û”Þc\ñ°³%?øó"Y„&ÃƒixrN¾ç\-ÛÚ~>
```

Does anyone know how I can get the source code of kickass.to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the response headers, you'll notice that they contain

```
content-encoding:gzip
```

If you inspect the source code of the page, you'll notice that the charset is UTF8.

So you need to read the stream using

```
inStream = new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```